# What is the method for accessing classes outside of the MainLayout class in a Kivy file?

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language

How do you reference methods from outside classes in a .kv file? For example, here is my main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random

class MyClass:
    def add():
        return 1 + 1

class MainLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And here is my main.kv:

```
<MainLayout>

    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Button:
            text: "Button"
            on_press: root.add()
```

My problem is being able to access the add() function from the .kv file since the function is not inside the MainLayout class, I just need a button that will call add(). What is the proper method for doing this?

I could probably define add() in the MainLayout class but that might be too messy with a large program with many classes and methods.

Comment: `MyClass` is not defined correctly. In any case, the way you access that is the way you would always access that, through an instance of that class. This is like asking "how do I access the `list.append` method?" Well, you have a list, e.g. `mylist = list("hello")`, and then you call the method: `mylist.append('z')`

Comment: Try `MyClass.add()` instead of `root.add()`

Comment: @ThomasWeller This results in "NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So I tried instantiating an object of MyClass, but trying to call add() on the object raises an "AttributeError: type object 'myObject' has no attribute 'add'"

Comment: It's not known from your code that how and where your class `MyClass` is connected to the GUI. Please provide enough details of that implementation.